# Sending message to user using id discord.net

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am trying to make a approve command to approve suggestions the suggestions command works but I seem to be having trouble figuring out the approve command.

I am using message IDs to get the suggestion and approve it as well as the message to get the user's ID to DM them.

Here is the code I have for the command:

```cs
 [Command("approve")]
        public async Task approve(ulong msgID, [Remainder]string approvealMessage)
        {
            IMessage suggestion = await Context.Channel.GetMessageAsync(msgID);


            await Context.Message.DeleteAsync();

            await suggestion.DeleteAsync();

            IUserMessage approvalmessage = await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Suggetion with message ID: " + msgID + " has been approved!");
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            await approvalmessage.DeleteAsync();


            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(serversuggestionidsypath + msgID + ".txt");
            string[] array = lines[1].Split(':');
            string suggestionText = array[1];

            await suggestion.Author.SendMessageAsync("Your suggestion below has been approved!\nSuggestion info:\n\nSuggestion: " + suggestionText + "\n\nStaff Input: " + approvealMessage);
        }
```

I have tried both author.sendmessageasync as well as getting the ID with Author and messaging them with UserExtensions.SendMessageAsync both stop the code at that and not letting anything below it not run.

Comment: It stops the code because it's throwing an error. You need to debug and see what that error is in order to fix your problem. Calling `SendMessageAsync` on the message author is valid. So that not your issue. Your error will point you in the direction of what needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Anu6is I have found the error but have no idea how I can fix this since it's just telling me you can't DM this person 

Discord.Net.HttpException: The server responded with error 50007: Cannot send messages to this user
   at Discord.Net.Queue.RequestBucket.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()

Comment: Then it's possible that the user has DMs blocked and you'd simply not be able to message them

Comment: @Anu6is I have figured it out. I was getting the user's ID via the message that the message was being sent by the bot so it was trying to DM the bot not the user.